# Rails: CoffeeScript is not defined on new Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting this error on a new rails app after creating a controller with rails g controller hello index. Rails is having a problem adding the css file and javascript file. Rails has worked fine before this:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rmlH.png)

Full Trace:

```
compile ((execjs):10:18)
eval (eval at <anonymous> ((execjs):24:8), <anonymous>:1:10)
(execjs):24:8
(execjs):30:14
(execjs):1:102
Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
Module.load (module.js:487:32)
tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:21:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:85:in `fetch'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:20:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:196:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `precompiled_assets'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:35:in `asset_precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:251:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:359:in `precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:363:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:348:in `find_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:169:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:169:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3755913814887945423_70333854259400'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:36:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: You'll get a better response if you copy/paste the error here instead of an image of it.

Comment: Have you changed your Gemfile?

Comment: I got the same error when running my app on a VM. Worked fine on my local machine.

Comment: The solution was to add the gem "coffee-script-source" to the gem file.

Comment: Does anyone know why this problem just appeared for several people?

Comment: @A.Bright there is a problem in coffe-script-source gem which was recently updated. the issue is that the source file in this version is empty. there is already an [open issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4403) , and it should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this problem with coffeescript and my quick fix was to add

```
gem "coffee-script-source", "~> 1.10.0"
```

to my Gemfile and run `bundle update coffee-script-source` in the console. Seems to be a problem with that gem.

Answer (score 4):

same problem, change version of gem coffee-script-source from 1.12.1 to 1.11.1

in Gemfile

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '= 1.11.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a different way. Remove the comments from

```
//require jquery
//require jquery_ujs
//require turbolinks
//require_tree.
```

from the */app/javascripts/application.js* file

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Comments beginning with `//=` are treated by Sprockets as directives not comments. What you are trying to do is removing `//require_tree` which will eliminate requiring the file called `hello.coffee` itself. In other words, you are not using CoffeeScript any more in the project (That's why it worked for you). It will also introduce other issues in compiling necessary scripts for your controllers and the app in general. So, I wont recommend doing this.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'll try max answer then. Thank you